# Is it true that $\sigma(\mathcal{A}\cap \mathcal{B})=\sigma(\mathcal{A}) \cap \sigma(\mathcal{B})$?

Tags: measure-theory

Does $\sigma(\mathcal{A}\cap  \mathcal{B})=\sigma(\mathcal{A}) \cap \sigma(\mathcal{B})$? where $\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B}$ are class of subsets of $\Omega$.
I tried some usual examples but did not find a counter example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not true. Take any set $\Omega \neq \emptyset$ and $A \subseteq \Omega$ such that $A \neq \emptyset$ and $A \neq \Omega$. If we define

$$\mathcal{A} := \{A\} \quad \text{and} \quad \mathcal{B} := \{A^c\}$$

then $$\sigma(\mathcal{A} \cap \mathcal{B}) = \{\emptyset,\Omega\}$$ whereas $$\sigma(\mathcal{A}) \cap \sigma(\mathcal{B}) = \{\emptyset,A,A^c,\Omega\}.$$

Answer (score 4):

Take $\Omega=\{1,2\}$ and $\mathcal{A}=\{\{1\}  \}$ and $\mathcal{B}=\{\{2\}  \}$. In fact you can show that $\sigma(\mathcal{A}\cap \mathcal{B})\subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{A}) \cap \sigma(\mathcal{B})$

Answer (score 3):

Another possibly interesting example: consider $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$, let $\mathcal{A}$ be the set of all open intervals, and $\mathcal{B}$ the set of all closed intervals.